# Count the number of non-zero elements of each column

Tags: r

Very new to R and I have a .rda file that contains a matrix of gene IDs and counts for each ID in 96 columns. It looks like this:

[image]

I want to get separate counts for the number of non-zero items in each column. I've been trying the sum() function in a loop, but perhaps I don't understand loop syntax in R. Any help appreciated.
Thanks!

Forest

Answer (score 79, accepted):

What about:

```
apply(your.matrix, 2, function(c)sum(c!=0))
```

Does this help?

**edit:**

Even better:

```
colSums(your.matrix != 0)
```

**edit 2:**

Here we go, with an example for ya:

```
> example = matrix(sample(c(0,0,0,100),size=70,replace=T),ncol=7)
> example
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
 [1,]    0  100    0    0  100    0  100
 [2,]  100    0    0    0    0    0  100
 [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0  100
 [4,]    0  100    0    0    0    0    0
 [5,]    0    0  100  100    0    0    0
 [6,]    0    0    0  100    0    0    0
 [7,]    0  100  100    0    0    0    0
 [8,]  100    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [9,]  100  100    0    0  100    0    0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0  100    0
> colSums(example != 0)
[1] 3 4 2 2 2 1 3
```

(new example, the previous example with '1' values was not suited to show that we are summing the *number* of cells, not their *contents*)

Comment: Sort of...this looks like it's giving me the sum of all counts for each column. Is there a way to modify it so that I get the number of elements of each column that are non-zero? So, if there are 1000 rows per column and a given column has 72 non-zero rows, the count for that column is 72? Thanks.

Comment: I believe your are mistaken: this code gives you *exactly* what you want... I am adding an example to convince you :)

Comment: This should work. `c!=0` is a vector of TRUE or FALSE, which gets coerced to 1 or 0 by `sum(...)`. So you are adding up 1's whenever c!=0, and that gives the count of non-zero elements.

Comment: I'm using this on a data frame containing all numeric values, but it's returning 'NA' for every column. I've tried a variation df = colSums(df > 0) to the same effect.
Can you advise please?

Comment: @FingerPickingGood you are likely having this error because you have NA values in every column. Try to add the argument `na.rm=TRUE`, for example: `colSums(df != 0, na.rm=T)`

Answer (score 8):

with `x` being a column or vector;

`length(which(x != 0))`

Answer (score 4):

Another method using `plyr`'s `numcolwise`:

```
library(plyr)

dat <- data.frame(a = sample(1:25, 25),
                  b = rep(0, 25),
                  c = sample(1:25, 25))
nonzero <- function(x) sum(x != 0)
numcolwise(nonzero)(dat)
   a b  c
1 25 0 25
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to count the number of columns that have zeros. This one uses `dplyr`.

First, `data.frame` operation mode needs to be `rowwise()` then, columns must be subset with `c_across()` which returns a vector, that can be used in any function that takes vectors. Finally the values are assigned to a new column using `mutate()`.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(a = sample(0:10, 100, replace = T),
                 b = sample(0:10, 100, replace = T),
                 c = sample(0:10, 100, replace = T))

df %>%
rowwise() %>%
mutate(`N_zeros` = sum(c_across(everything()) == 0))
```

This idea can also be modified for any other operation that would take all or a subset of columns for row-wise operation.

See [documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/c_across.html) of `c_across()` for more details. Tested with `dplyr` version 1.0.6.