# Count rows in table where almost all fieds have 0 value. database SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with number of 50 fields named like Sti_01, Sti_02, Sti_03, ..., Sti_50.

As an example:

```
 ColumnID | YEAR | Sti_01 | Sti_02 | ... | Sti_50 
----------+------+--------+--------+-----+-------
 1        | 2015 |   0    |  0     |  0  |   0
 2        | 2014 |   45   |  0     |  5  |   0
 3        | 2014 |   0    |  0     |  0  |   0
 4        | 2015 |   0    |  0     |  0  |   0 
 5        | 2014 |   67   |  2     |  3  |   0
```

I need count rows where all Sti_XX columns have 0 value - in our example rows with ColumnID 1, 3 and 4. Answer will be 3.

Comment: Horrible table design. Have one value/row instead of all those columns.

Comment: sorry maaan - it made for a better understanding

Comment: may this helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22286957/count-the-number-of-non-zero-elements-of-each-column

Comment: Unfortunately in this question there is no transact sql code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not filtering each column value explicitly?

```
select count(*)
from table_name
where Sti_01 = 0
and Sti_02 = 0
...
and Sti_50 = 0
```

Or, if you prefer an horizontal code layout

```
select count(*)
from table_name
where (Sti_01, Sti_02, ... , Sti_50) in 
((0,0,...,0))
```

Comment: Ooo the amount of code will be so big - maybe you have something better and nicer version?

Comment: the amount of columns is also big :)

Comment: The second version is not working in sql server. But the first is good  - i will use it)

Comment: Would you accept the answer please? Thank you.

Comment: Simimmo - when i have 15 points i will accept the question) Please wait!

Answer (score 1):

What a bad table design! Anyway:

```
WITH  unpivoted
        AS (
             SELECT ColumnID, Sti, [Value]
             FROM   ( SELECT  * FROM MyTable ) AS p 
             UNPIVOT  ( [value] FOR Sti IN 
                ( [Sti_01], [Sti_02], ..., [Sti_50] ) ) AS unpvt
           )
  SELECT  columnId
  FROM    unpivoted
  GROUP BY columnId
  HAVING  SUM([Value]) = 0;
```